# Qtimer: calling different slot every 2000 ms

Tags: qtimer

I'm working on a project but I'm new of c++ and Qt and I'm having some big troubles.
I have my program on Qt with my GUI interface and I already have done all the Slots related to the buttons in the GUI. Now what I need is to call different slot in sequences every 2000ms, to explain better, the Slots are for example

```
    void on_setPort_clicked();
    void on_portSearch_clicked();
    void on_openPort_clicked();
    void on_ledON_clicked();
```

I need the program (when I push the relative button) to execute the first one, then after 2 second the second one, then after 2 second again the third one and so on...
How can I do this? For now I understood how to make a certain Slot to execute every 2 second but I need to have a different slots every 2 seconds. I dont know what to put in my .h file and in my .cpp

Thanks guys, hope to have been clear in my answer, sorry for my english but I'm italian.

PS I also need a slot like for examples on_STOP_clicked with a command that will stop sequences to continue like a timer stop when I push the relative button in the GUI

Answer (score 0):

QT Slots are just normal functions so what you need to do is have the timer call one slot and then have that slot determine which function should be called next and then call it.

```
//State held somewhere else that makes sense in your progrma
//preferably not just a global
int nextSlot =0;

void timer_slot(){
switch(nextSlot){
case 0:
    first_slot();
    break;
case 1:
    second_slot();
    break;
etc....
}
nextSlot++ % (number_of_other_functions-1);//-1 as the array is 0 indexed
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks man, so if I understood right I have to make a normal timer that will tipically execute the same slot every 2000ms but I'll put the code you post in to that slot in order to make it execute all the other slot in sequence, am I right?